# How to clean some columns of my dataset from a particular string?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, data-science

I am trying to clean my dataset. It has few columns which have all String/float/int (for name/pay/overtimepay) values but few rows contain 'Not provided' as a value.

```
newData = data[~data['BasePay'].isin(['Not Provided'])]
newData = data[~data['BasePay'].str.contains('Not Provided', na=False)]
print(newData['BasePay'].mean())
```

and

```
df = data.select_dtypes(object)
mask = ~df.apply(lambda series: series.str.contains('Not Provided')).any(axis=1)
no_eco = data[mask]
```

to clean the column of 'BasePay' and calculate mean but failed. I'd appreciate if you could help. [Image of the concerned rows in my dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2AO9.png)

Comment: StackOverFlow Pandas 101 advice: don't paste images! This will increase your chances of getting a good answer... and likely within 10 minutes of asking... Copy and paste the actual data into your question... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: Better yet, paste the code to generate a dummy / sample dataset with few rows, so that people can copy paste it and quickly workout and answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your data has a variation between `Not Provided` and `Not provided` with a lower `p`, so is better to use a `df.replace` with `regex=True` including this alternation (`[pP]rovided`). The choice of replace value depends on how you gonna handle your data, but here I used `np.NaN` from numpy library. After the replace you can use `fillna(0)` on the column with `BasePay`, however the column type is `object` so it needs to be interpreted as float (`.astype(float)`) before calculating the mean.

Input used as **data.csv**

```
       ID               Name                    Occupation            Pay    OvertimePay        BasePay           Val4    Val5
0  148646   Carolyn A Wilson     Human Services Technician              0              0              0              0    0.00
1  148647       Not provided                  Not provided   Not Provided   Not Provided   Not Provided   Not Provided    0.00
2  148648     Joann Anderson   Communications Dispatcher 2              0              0              0              0    0.00
3  148649        Leon Walker                     Custodian              0              0              0              0    0.00
4  148650      Roy 1 Tillery                     Custodian              0              0              0              0    0.00
5  148651       Not provided                  Not provided   Not Provided   Not Provided   Not Provided   Not Provided    0.00
6  148652       Not provided                  Not provided   Not Provided   Not Provided   Not Provided   Not Provided    0.00
7  148653       Not provided                  Not provided   Not Provided   Not Provided   Not Provided   Not Provided    0.00
8  148654          Joe Lopez    Counselor, Log Cabin Ranch              0              0        -618.13              0 -618.13
```

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", sep=";")
print(df)

df = df.replace("Not [pP]rovided", np.NaN, regex=True)

BasePay_mean = df["BasePay"].fillna(0).astype(float).mean()
print(BasePay_mean)
```

Output from **BasePay_mean**

```
-68.68111111111111
```